# How to use reflection to get the BindingExpression (and value) for controls having a ContentProperty in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, reflection, binding, contentproperty

I need to use reflection to get the binding value in a control that is a `DataGridTemplateColumn` (e.g `HyperLinkButton`). Does anyone know how I might do this?

It seems simple enough to do this with a `TextBlock` because it has a `TextProperty` dependency property, but I can’t seem to get a binding expression from a control that does not have an immediate `TextProperty`. Here is the code I’m using to acquire the binding expression for a `TextBlock`:

```
FrameworkElement fe = (FrameworkElement)dependencyObj;
FieldInfo fi = fe.GetType().GetField("TextProperty");
BindingExpression bindingExpression = fe.GetBindingExpression((DependencyProperty)fi.GetValue(null))
```

However, the following code never works for a dependency object that is a `HyperLinkButton`:

```
FieldInfo fi = fe.GetType().GetField("ContentProperty");
```

Does anyone know how I might be able to get the `BindingExpression` (and binding value) for the content of a `HyperLinkButton`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried adding the correct binding flags for that field? It sounds like a case of inadaquate binding flags when using reflection.
TextBlock has a the Text static field right on TextBlock, where as HyperlinkButton has Content inherited from ContentControl.

Try using the Static & Public & FlattenedHierarchy binding flags:

```
FieldInfo fi = fe.GetType().GetField("ContentProperty", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
```

adding the FlattenHierarchy reflection binding flag should tell reflection to look up in the class hierarchy to find that public static field.

Comment: Hi Justin,

Thanks for your help. With the addition of that particular flags enum, I was able to solve the issue.